# validar si un campo existe - php

Tags: php

buen día, necesito que verifique en la base de datos si el registro del documento existe en base de datos me haga algo pero si no me haga otra cosa, lo he intentado pero en el row de la consulta no me arroja nada:

```php
$documento="11104981901",

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "witty2";
$username = "witty2";
$password = "Pepe=00";
// Create connection
$conexion = mysqli_connect(
  $servername, $username, $password, $database
);
// Check connection
if (!$conexion) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_close($conexion);

$resultado = $conexion->query(
"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE documento='$documento');"
);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

if ($row[0]=="1") {
// Aqui colocas el código que tu deseas realizar
// cuando el dato existe en la base de datos
}else{
// Aqui colocas el código que tu deseas realizar
// cuando el dato NO existe en la base de datos
}
```

Comment: Esto `mysqli_close($conexion);` debe ir al final, estás cerrando la conexión antes de tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Estás cerrando la conexión antes de tiempo
2. Si quieres verificar la existencia de registros es mejor contar con un `SELECT COUNT(*)`
3. Convendría que uses consultas preparadas: dan seguridad al código en aquellos escenarios en que `$documento` sea proporcionado por el usuario. Además, las consultas preparadas son más rápidas, porque trazan el plan de ejecución en el manejador de base de datos.
4. Deberías controlar el flujo completo, emitiendo en cada caso un mensaje de lo que ha ocurrido.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código podría escribirse así:

```
$documento="11104981901",

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "witty2";
$username = "witty2";
$password = "Pepe=00";
// Create connection
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
$outPut=array();
if (!$conexion) {
    $outPut["error"]=sprintf("Connection failed: %s",mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE documento=?";
    if ( $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql) ) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $documento);   
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        if ( $total>0 ) {
            $outPut['success']=sprintf('Se encontraron %d filas',$total);
        } else {
            $outPut['error']='No se encontraron filas';
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='Error preparando la consulta';
    }
}
var_dump($outPut);
```

Es un código más largo que el tuyo, pero es un código maduro, que verifica todas las situaciones eventuales, y además es seguro al usar consultas preparadas.

La lógica seguida es simple: `$outPut` tendrá una clave `error` cuando cualquier error haya ocurrido y una clave `success` cuando ocurra la contrario. Para consumir la respuesta se podría hacer algo así:

```
if ( array_key_exists('error', $outPut) ) {
    #Hubo error, lanzar tu política de manejo de errores
    printf("ERROR: %s",$outPut["error"]);
} else {
    #Todo OK, mostrarlo o pasarlo a la vista
    echo $outPut["success"];
}
```